# Call google API with access token

Tags: node.js, google-api

After login from client side and receive access token on the server side, I want to call Google API for taking info. Can I in server-side just call google API, without insert API key and another credential but only with the access token?

Something like that:

```
plus.people.get({
    resourceName: 'people/me',
    personFields: 'emailAddresses,names',
    auth: accessToken}, (err, response) => {
      console.log(response);
    });
```

I'm actually using node.js

Comment: You either need `api-key` or `access-token` with `oauth` clientId and clientSecret.

Comment: I insert access-token but the call returns undefined

Comment: `console.log(err) ` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I understood that you want to use people.get using access token. If my understanding is correct, how about this sample script?

#### Sample script :

```
var google = require('googleapis');
var plus = google.people('v1');
var OAuth2 = google.auth.OAuth2;
var oauth2Client = new OAuth2();
oauth2Client.setCredentials({access_token: accessToken});
plus.people.get({
    resourceName: 'people/me',
    personFields: 'emailAddresses,names',
    auth: oauth2Client}, (err, response) => {
      console.log(response);
    });
```

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.